# Condition to check if output contains any Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a flow that triggers when a new form is submitted. I want to use a condition to check if a certain question has any text or symbol in it.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to check if the anwer to question is empty or not OR only check for certain/predefined characters/symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if anwer to question is empty or not, you can try either of below solutions:

**Solution 1**:

In case if the `Outputs` in your condition is of type text/string, you can use the condition like this:

[image]

**Solution 2**:

You can use expression like below to test the empty text:

```
equals(empty(outputs('Compose')))
```

[image]

Both the expressions on left and right hand side of condition are added using Dynamic Content panel > Expression section like:

[image]